# Sum 2 string numbers

Tags: java, string, sum, int

I've looked it up, but couldn't get a real answer to that. So I want to know how to sum up 2 string numbers together.
for example:

`String a = "8";
String b = "1";`

I want to sum both of them to "9". Is that possible?

Thanks.

edit - that is the code Im trying to use:

```
String num = Integer.toString(i);
    String doubleNumber = Integer.toString(i * i);
    int length = doubleNumber.length();
    String firstNumber;
    String secondNumber;
    for (int q = 0; q < length; q++) {
        firstNumber = doubleNumber.substring(0, Math.min(doubleNumber.length(), q+1));
        secondNumber = doubleNumber.substring(q+1, Math.min(doubleNumber.length(), doubleNumber.length()));
        String result = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(firstNumber) + Integer.parseInt(secondNumber));
        if(num.equals(result)) {
            isKaprekar = true;
        }
    }
```

edit 2 - I have no idea how, but I opened another class, pasted the same code, and it just magically worked. It makes 0 sense, cause its the same project, everything is the same, but it works now, so I don't care. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Use Java's `Integer` class, `parseInt` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: I already tried that, but Im getting the next error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "".
I understand that the string containts for some reason "", but I have no idea why or how.

Comment: So it sounds like you're passing an empty string, and not "8" or "1".

Comment: When I try to print the value of the strings, Im getting the values of 8 and 1.

Comment: Try posing your code here with the `parseInt`s, there may be another issue.

Comment: I see no issue: https://www.ideone.com/7mobaK

Comment: *code is in the post*

Comment: @msacco: No, don't put code in a comment. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Just done that. Sorry.

Comment: What problem are you facing while using your code? (put that description in the question itself).

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "".

Comment: In that case your question is incorrectly worded. What you have now `String result = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(firstNumber) + Integer.parseInt(secondNumber));` is correct way to answer question in current form. But problem you are facing is caused by fact that one of values you used as arguments of `Integer.parseInt` is empty string `""` so that is the problem you want to ask about. In your next questions please state clearly what problem you are trying to solve, to avoid situation we call [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: I'll try to explain better next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a  method called [`Integer#parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Integer.html) which returns an int representation of a given String (if possible):

```
String a = "8";
String b = "1";
int sum = Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b);
```

If you want to change it back to a String, use [`String#valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)):

```
String s = String.valueOf(sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd parse them to `int`s, add them, and then convert the result back to a string:

```
String result = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert both to `Integers`:

```
String a = "8";
String b = "1";
int sum = Integer.parseInt(a, 10) + Integer.parseInt(b, 10);
```

The second argument of `Integer.parseInt()` is the radix, which tells which number base to use. You can leave this argument out altogether and it will default to using a radix of `10`:

```
int sum = Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b);
```

If you want to convert them back to a string, just pass the value into `String.valueOf()`:

```
String sumString = String.valueOf(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
String a = "8"; 
String b = "1";
String sum = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a)
                       +Integer.parseInt(b));

 //printing sum
 System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string to `int` using `Integer.parseInt(string)`and add them as normal integers.

For example :

`String result = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b));`
should give you the desired string value as `"9"`